# Extending database factory class to use auditing class

Tags: c#

I'm the the process of adding change auditing to my existing `DB` class which encapsulates database calls.

Previously I would just pass in a `String` and a `SqlParameter` array but now I've added the class 'DBData' to contain the values required for the auditing.

I'm not sure whether passing in this `DBData` object and then calling `AuditAction()` is the cleanest way to organise the code though and would appreciate input.

```
public class DBData
{
    public DBData() { }
    public DBData(object newValue, object oldValue)
    {
        this.NewValue = newValue;
        this.OldValue = oldValue;
    }

    public int UserKey { get; set; }
    public object NewValue { get; set; }
    public object OldValue { get; set; }

    public string Query { get; set; }
    public SqlParameter[] Parameters { get; set; }
}

public static class DB
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Connection String to Local Machines Database
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly string connectionString   = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    private static readonly DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");

    public static void Update(DBData data)
    {
        try
        {
            AuditAction(data.UserKey, data.NewValue, data.OldValue);
            InsertData(data.Query, data.Parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts data into the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">query</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">declared parameters</param>
    public static void InsertData(string sql, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = sql;

                    if (parameters != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                        {
                            if (parameter != null)
                                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two objects and log the properties which have changed to the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userKey">id of logged in user</param>
    /// <param name="newObject">object with changes</param>
    /// <param name="oldObject">copy of object before changes</param>
    public static void AuditAction(int userKey, object newObject, object oldObject)
    {
        try
        {
            ChangeLogger logger = new ChangeLogger(userKey, newObject, oldObject);

            // The name of the object should give a good idication of what the change was from
            // E.g. ScanSchedule is obviously a change to the scan schedule
            string className = newObject.GetType().Name; 

            logger.Audit();
            if (!logger.Success)
            {
                throw logger.Exception;
            }

            foreach (ChangeLog log in logger.Changes)
            {
                LogAction(log.ObjectId, log.ValueNew, log.ValueOld, log.Property, className, DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert data into the ChangeLog table of the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userKey">id of user who made the change</param>
    /// <param name="valueNew">changed value</param>
    /// <param name="valueOld">value before change</param>
    /// <param name="property">property being changed</param>
    /// <param name="className">class where change took place</param>
    /// <param name="changeDate">time change made</param>
    private static void LogAction(long userKey, string valueNew, string valueOld, string property, string className, DateTime changeDate)
    {
        try
        {
            string insertLog
                = "INSERT INTO ChangeLog "
                + "(UserKey, ObjectName, Property, NewValue, PreviousValue, ChangeDate) "
                + "VALUES "
                + "(@UserKey, @ObjectName, @Property, @NewValue, @PreviousValue, @ChangeDate)";

            DB.InsertData(insertLog,
                new[]
                {
                    new SqlParameter("@UserKey", userKey),
                    new SqlParameter("@ObjectName", className),
                    new SqlParameter("@Property", property),
                    new SqlParameter("@NewValue", valueNew),
                    new SqlParameter("@PreviousValue", valueOld),
                    new SqlParameter("@ChangeDate", changeDate),
                });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
private static void UpdateScanSchedule(DBData data, ScanSchedule schedule)
{
    try
    {
        data.Query
            = "UPDATE ScanSchedules " 
            + "SET GroupID = @GroupID, ScheduleType =@ScheduleType, " 
            + "RunDays =@RunDays ,RunDate =@RunDate, Description = @Description, " 
            + "RunTime = @RunTime, Ranges = @Ranges , Devices = @Devices, Excluded = @Excluded " 
            + "WHERE ScanScheduleID = @ScanScheduleID";

        data.Parameters
            = new[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@GroupID", schedule.GroupID),
                new SqlParameter("@ScheduleType", schedule.ScheduleType),
                new SqlParameter("@RunDays", schedule.RunDays),
                new SqlParameter("@RunDate", schedule.RunDate),
                new SqlParameter("@Description", schedule.Description),
                new SqlParameter("@RunTime", schedule.RunTime),
                new SqlParameter("@Ranges", schedule.Ranges),
                new SqlParameter("@Devices", schedule.Devices),
                new SqlParameter("@Excluded", schedule.Excluded),
                new SqlParameter("@ScanScheduleID", schedule.ScanScheduleID),
            };

        DB.Update(data);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}

private static void Example(ScanSchedule oldSchedule, int userKey)
{
    try
    {
        ScanSchedule schedule   = new ScanSchedule();
        schedule.GroupID        = GroupID;
        schedule.Description    = Description;
        schedule.Devices        = Util.ValidIPAddressList(Devices);
        schedule.Excluded       = Util.ValidIPAddressList(Excluded);
        schedule.Ranges         = Ranges;
        schedule.RunDate        = RunDate;
        schedule.RunDays        = RunDays;
        schedule.RunTime        = DateTime.Parse(ScanTime);
        schedule.ScanScheduleID = ScanScheduleID;
        schedule.ScheduleType   = ScheduleType;

        UpdateScanSchedule(new DBData(schedule, oldSchedule, userKey), schedule);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This is a nice detailed question, I hope you'll have good reviews!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I don't see any reason to wrap code in an exception and just re-throw it (that is essentially like  not having the wrapper in the first place).
   Also I believe that just clutters the code so I would consider removing the exception wrapper altogether.
2. The public Update method just delegates to the Insert method.  That seems a bit counter intuitive to me.  Update to my mind would perform an
   operation on an existing object, while insert adds a new one.  I would consider renaming Insert to Update and have it as a method overload.
3. On second thoughts the Insert isn't really an insert at all as it will depend on the Sql supplied.  It would consider calling that ExecuteNonQuery
   to better indicate it's intent.
4. As @Malachi pointed out, I'm not sure of the factory implementation.  To better abstract your db from the core DbProvider factories I might
   consider creating my own interface and hiding everything behind that.  This would allow your DbRepository to have no concept of where/how connections
   are created either by using internal framework facilities or some other mechanism.
5. Does the class really need to be static?  That limits what you can do in my opinion.  I might consider writing an extension method to
   create a db if you don't want to continue new'ing it everywhere.  Otherwise you could consider injecting the DbRepository class into the methods
   you need and only do it's construct in one place?

Here is an alternative code solution:

```
class DBData
{
    public DBData() { }
    public DBData(object newValue, object oldValue)
    {
        this.NewValue = newValue;
        this.OldValue = oldValue;
    }

    public int UserKey { get; set; }
    public object NewValue { get; set; }
    public object OldValue { get; set; }

    public string Query { get; set; }
    public SqlParameter[] Parameters { get; set; }
}

interface IDbRepository 
{
    void Update(DBData data);
}

class DbRepository : IDbRepository
{
    private readonly IDbFactory _dbFactory;

    public DbContext(IDbFactory dbFactory)
    {
        _dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }

    public void ExecuteNonQuery(DBData data)
    {
        Audit(data.UserKey, data.NewValue, data.OldValue);
        ExecuteNonQuery(data.Query, data.Parameters);
    }

    private void ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (DbConnection connection = _dbFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (DbCommand command = _dbFactory.CreateCommand(connection, parameters))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two objects and log the properties which have changed to the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userKey">id of logged in user</param>
    /// <param name="newObject">object with changes</param>
    /// <param name="oldObject">copy of object before changes</param>
    public void Audit(int userKey, object newObject, object oldObject)
    {
        ChangeLogger logger = new ChangeLogger(userKey, newObject, oldObject);

        // The name of the object should give a good indication of what the change was from
        // E.g. ScanSchedule is obviously a change to the scan schedule
        string className = newObject.GetType().Name; 

        logger.Audit();
        if (!logger.Success)
        {
            throw logger.Exception;
        }

        logger.Changes.ForEach(log => Log(log.ObjectId, log.ValueNew, log.ValueOld, log.Property, className, DateTime.Now)); 
    }

    // I might consider moving this method into it's own Logger class
    private void Log(long userKey, string valueNew, string valueOld, string property, string className, DateTime changeDate)
    {
        string insertLog
            = "INSERT INTO ChangeLog "
            + "(UserKey, ObjectName, Property, NewValue, PreviousValue, ChangeDate) "
            + "VALUES "
            + "(@UserKey, @ObjectName, @Property, @NewValue, @PreviousValue, @ChangeDate)";

        Insert(insertLog,
            new[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@UserKey", userKey),
                new SqlParameter("@ObjectName", className),
                new SqlParameter("@Property", property),
                new SqlParameter("@NewValue", valueNew),
                new SqlParameter("@PreviousValue", valueOld),
                new SqlParameter("@ChangeDate", changeDate),
            });
    }
}

static class DbRepositoryProvider
{
    private static readonly string connectionString  = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    public static IDbRepository GetRepository()
    {
        var factory = new DbFactory(connectionString);

        return new DbRepository(factory);
    }
}

class DbFactory : IDbFactory
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private static readonly DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");

    public DbFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public DbConnection CreateConnection() 
    {
        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;

        return connection;
    }

    public DbCommand CreateCommand(DbConnection connection)
    {
        var  command = factory.CreateCommand();     
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = sql;

        return command;
    }

    public DbCommand CreateCommand(DbConnection connection, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        var command = CreateCommand(connection);
        AddAnyParameters(command, parameters);

        return command;     
    }

    private void AddAnyParameters(DbCommand, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null) return;

        foreach (var parameter in parameters.Where(p => p != null))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }   
    }   
}
```

And it's usage from your example would look something like:

```
private static void UpdateScanSchedule(DBData data, ScanSchedule schedule)
{
    data.Query
        = "UPDATE ScanSchedules " 
        + "SET GroupID = @GroupID, ScheduleType =@ScheduleType, " 
        + "RunDays =@RunDays ,RunDate =@RunDate, Description = @Description, " 
        + "RunTime = @RunTime, Ranges = @Ranges , Devices = @Devices, Excluded = @Excluded " 
        + "WHERE ScanScheduleID = @ScanScheduleID";

    data.Parameters
        = new[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@GroupID", schedule.GroupID),
            new SqlParameter("@ScheduleType", schedule.ScheduleType),
            new SqlParameter("@RunDays", schedule.RunDays),
            new SqlParameter("@RunDate", schedule.RunDate),
            new SqlParameter("@Description", schedule.Description),
            new SqlParameter("@RunTime", schedule.RunTime),
            new SqlParameter("@Ranges", schedule.Ranges),
            new SqlParameter("@Devices", schedule.Devices),
            new SqlParameter("@Excluded", schedule.Excluded),
            new SqlParameter("@ScanScheduleID", schedule.ScanScheduleID),
        };

    var db = DbRepositoryProvider.GetRepository();
    db.Update(data);
}
```

Comment: What library is [IDbFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441278.aspx) from? I'm not familiar with it and it's not clear from the MSDN page.

Comment: No library.  I just hadn't included it in the code.  However should be simple enough to create as required.

Comment: I thought so, it was just a little odd that it was also on msdn!

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is create a class that will create a factory and take parameters when it is constructed so that you don't have to assign all the properties the way you are, you just give the new factory wrapper all the information and then call what you need built, with a simple method call from the Factory object you create.

---

Inside your `LogAction` you should not be creating a SQL string, you should be passing parameters to a stored procedure on your database instead.

You are not separating your concerns,  your data insertion should be done by the database and the code should just be sending the information.

you are already creating parameters and setting up an execute for a query, why not just turn it into a stored procedure call?

---

You can only use Object initialization if you were creating a brand new `DbConnection`

```
using (DbConnection connection = new DbConnection() {ConnectionString = connectionString})
{
    ...
}
```

<s>Here is something that seems a little out of place</s>

```
using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    .....
}
```

you have a factory that is supposed to create a connection, but the method doesn't take a `connectionString` as a parameter?  This seems really redundant.

This is okay, it seems, but I think that I would do it a little bit differently

```
using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection()
          {ConnectionString = connectionString})
{
     ....
}
```

called `Object Initializer Syntax` another member on CodeReview showed it to me, and this looks like a good place to use it, along with the next using block as well

```
using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = sql;
    .......
}
```

it would look like this:

```
using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand()
       { Connection = connection,
         CommandType = CommandType.Text,
         CommandText = sql }
{
     ....   
}
```

Comment: Just a note.  I don't believe you can use object initialiser like that.  It is only available when using the new construct I believe.

Comment: I will look into it.... @dreza, but I think I heard that before somewhere....

Comment: @Dreza, I have edited my answer, it is not possible to use `Object initializer syntax` unless you are creating a brand new `IDisposable` object.